# accessing node modules from index.html from public folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, node-modules

How can i access node_modules like angular from my index.html file

**File structure like so**

node_modules

public

- jsfolder
- cssfolder
- index.html

server.js

I know this doesnt work but its what I have so far in index.html

```
  <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

I know I shouldnt put node modules in public so do i serve it with node or something.

Answer (score 0):

(A) Best solution for you may be [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)

(B) But yeah, this is pretty annoying. You're right that you shouldn't have node_modules in public. Unfortunately the real answer isn't a simple one. You should copy the files you need into `public/lib` using something like Gulp or Webpack.

This guide is pretty good:
https://george.webb.uno/posts/gulp-and-npm-for-front-end-web-development

(C) To use a package manager exactly the way you specified, Bower is your friend (https://bower.io/)

Bower is on its way out and you'll want to move to NPM + Webpack eventually. To do that, look at Parcel (https://parceljs.org/)